# TableLayout children does not get drawn on PdfDocument.Page.Canvas

Tags: java, android, pdf, canvas, layout-inflater

I can't seem to get get the children of my `TableLayout` to be printed on my `Canvas` object which is to be used to generate a PDF file using the `PdfDocument` native to Android.

The only thing that is displayed on the PDF document are my Line Chart and the Inflated layout without the views that are added programmatically.

Here is the following function that supposedly generates the said PDF:

```
private void generatePDF() throws IOException {
        SAIHelper.createAndShowToast(getActivity(), "Generating PDF, please wait...");

        PdfDocument pdfDocument = new PdfDocument();

        PdfDocument.PageInfo pageInfo = new PdfDocument.PageInfo.Builder(mLineChart.getWidth(), mLineChart.getHeight() + 842, 1).create();

        PdfDocument.Page page = pdfDocument.startPage(pageInfo);

        System.out.println("CHART WIDTH: " + mLineChart.getWidth());
        System.out.println("CHART HEIGHT: " + mLineChart.getHeight());

        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        TableLayout tableLayout = (TableLayout) layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.table_layout, null);
        tableLayout.measure(mLineChart.getWidth(), mLineChart.getHeight());
        tableLayout.layout(0, 0, mLineChart.getWidth(), mLineChart.getWidth());

        Canvas canvas = page.getCanvas();
        canvas.save();
        mLineChart.draw(canvas);
        canvas.restore();
        canvas.translate(0, mLineChart.getHeight());

        int totalScore = 0;

        int sad_lonely_unhappy = 0;
        int happy = 0;
        int disturbed_no_focus = 0;
        int feeling_of_isolation = 0;
        int sleep_problems = 0;
        int hopeless = 0;
        int fatigued_stressed = 0;
        int pessimism = 0;
        int uneasy_unstable = 0;
        int moody = 0;
        int emotional = 0;
        int eating_problems = 0;
        int low_self_esteem = 0;
        int suicidal = 0;
        int anxious = 0;
        int pretending_to_be_happy = 0;
        int have_no_emotional_support = 0;

        int days = 0;

        for (Entry entry : mEntries) {
            JsonObject jsonObject = (JsonObject) entry.getData();
            days++;
            for (Map.Entry<String, JsonElement> entry1 : jsonObject.entrySet()) {
                for (Map.Entry<String, JsonElement> entry2 : entry1.getValue().getAsJsonObject().entrySet()) {
                    switch (entry1.getKey()) {
                        case "sad_lonely_unhappy":
                            sad_lonely_unhappy += entry2.getValue().getAsInt();
                            break;
                        case "happy":
                            happy += entry2.getValue().getAsInt();
                            break;
                        case "disturbed_no_focus":
                            disturbed_no_focus += entry2.getValue().getAsInt();
                            break;
                        case "feeling_of_isolation":
                            feeling_of_isolation += entry2.getValue().getAsInt();
                            break;
                        case "sleep_problems":
                            sleep_problems += entry2.getValue().getAsInt();
                            break;
                        case "hopeless":
                            hopeless += entry2.getValue().getAsInt();
                            break;
                        case "fatigued_stressed":
                            fatigued_stressed += entry2.getValue().getAsInt();
                            break;
                        case "pessimism":
                            pessimism += entry2.getValue().getAsInt();
                            break;
                        case "uneasy_unstable":
                            uneasy_unstable += entry2.getValue().getAsInt();
                            break;
                        case "moody":
                            moody += entry2.getValue().getAsInt();
                            break;
                        case "emotional":
                            emotional += entry2.getValue().getAsInt();
                            break;
                        case "eating_problems":
                            eating_problems += entry2.getValue().getAsInt();
                            break;
                        case "low_self_esteem":
                            low_self_esteem += entry2.getValue().getAsInt();
                            break;
                        case "suicidal":
                            suicidal += entry2.getValue().getAsInt();
                            break;
                        case "anxious":
                            anxious += entry2.getValue().getAsInt();
                            break;
                        case "pretending_to_be_happy":
                            pretending_to_be_happy += entry2.getValue().getAsInt();
                            break;
                        case "have_no_emotional_support":
                            have_no_emotional_support += entry2.getValue().getAsInt();
                            break;
                    }
                    totalScore += entry2.getValue().getAsInt();
                }
            }
        }

        String[] array = {"sad_lonely_unhappy",
                "happy",
                "disturbed_no_focus",
                "feeling_of_isolation",
                "sleep_problems",
                "hopeless",
                "fatigued_stressed",
                "pessimism",
                "uneasy_unstable",
                "moody",
                "emotional",
                "eating_problems",
                "low_self_esteem",
                "suicidal",
                "anxious",
                "pretending_to_be_happy",
                "have_no_emotional_support"};

        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            TableRow tableRow = (TableRow) layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.row_layout, tableLayout, false);
            tableRow.measure(mLineChart.getWidth(), mLineChart.getHeight());
            tableRow.layout(0, 0, mLineChart.getWidth(), mLineChart.getWidth());
//            tableRow.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

            TextView percentage = new TextView(getContext());
            percentage.setText(array[i].replace('_', ' ').toUpperCase());
            percentage.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP,8);
            percentage.setTypeface(Typeface.create("avenir", Typeface.NORMAL));
            percentage.setTextAlignment(View.TEXT_ALIGNMENT_CENTER);
            percentage.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#414953"));
//            percentage.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

            TextView category = new TextView(getContext());
            category.setText(array[i].replace('_', ' ').toUpperCase());
            category.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP,8);
            category.setTypeface(Typeface.create("avenir", Typeface.NORMAL));
            category.setTextAlignment(View.TEXT_ALIGNMENT_CENTER);
            category.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#414953"));
            category.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

            TextView avg = new TextView(getContext());
            avg.setText(array[i].replace('_', ' ').toUpperCase());
            avg.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP,8);
            avg.setTypeface(Typeface.create("avenir", Typeface.NORMAL));
            avg.setTextAlignment(View.TEXT_ALIGNMENT_CENTER);
            avg.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#414953"));
//            avg.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

            int theInt = 0;

            switch (array[i]) {
                case "sad_lonely_unhappy":
                    theInt = sad_lonely_unhappy;
                    percentage.setText(((sad_lonely_unhappy / totalScore) * 100) + "%");
                    break;
                case "happy":
                    theInt = happy;
                    percentage.setText(((happy / totalScore) * 100) + "%");
                    break;
                case "disturbed_no_focus":
                    theInt = disturbed_no_focus;
                    percentage.setText(((disturbed_no_focus / totalScore) * 100) + "%");
                    break;
                case "feeling_of_isolation":
                    theInt = feeling_of_isolation;
                    percentage.setText(((feeling_of_isolation / totalScore) * 100) + "%");
                    break;
                case "sleep_problems":
                    theInt = sleep_problems;
                    percentage.setText(((sleep_problems / totalScore) * 100) + "%");
                    break;
                case "hopeless":
                    theInt = hopeless;
                    percentage.setText(((hopeless / totalScore) * 100) + "%");
                    break;
                case "fatigued_stressed":
                    percentage.setText(((fatigued_stressed / totalScore) * 100) + "%");
                    theInt = fatigued_stressed;
                    break;
                case "pessimism":
                    percentage.setText(((pessimism / totalScore) * 100) + "%");
                    theInt = pessimism;
                    break;
                case "uneasy_unstable":
                    percentage.setText(((uneasy_unstable / totalScore) * 100) + "%");
                    theInt = uneasy_unstable;
                    break;
                case "moody":
                    percentage.setText(((moody / totalScore) * 100) + "%");
                    theInt = moody;
                    break;
                case "emotional":
                    percentage.setText(((emotional / totalScore) * 100) + "%");
                    theInt = emotional;
                    break;
                case "eating_problems":
                    percentage.setText(((eating_problems / totalScore) * 100) + "%");
                    theInt = eating_problems;
                    break;
                case "low_self_esteem":
                    percentage.setText(((low_self_esteem / totalScore) * 100) + "%");
                    theInt = low_self_esteem;
                    break;
                case "suicidal":
                    percentage.setText(((suicidal / totalScore) * 100) + "%");
                    theInt = suicidal;
                    break;
                case "anxious":
                    percentage.setText(((anxious / totalScore) * 100) + "%");
                    theInt = anxious;
                    break;
                case "pretending_to_be_happy":
                    percentage.setText(((pretending_to_be_happy / totalScore) * 100) + "%");
                    theInt = pretending_to_be_happy;
                    break;
                case "have_no_emotional_support":
                    percentage.setText(((have_no_emotional_support / totalScore) * 100) + "%");
                    theInt = have_no_emotional_support;
                    break;
            }

            avg.setText(theInt / days + "");

            tableRow.addView(percentage);
            tableRow.addView(category);
            tableRow.addView(avg);

            tableLayout.addView(tableRow);

            System.out.println("TABLE LAYOUT CHILDREN: " + tableLayout.getChildCount());
        }


//
//        tableLayout.invalidate();
//        tableLayout.refreshDrawableState();

        tableLayout.draw(canvas);

        pdfDocument.finishPage(page);
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-dd-MM_HH_mm_ss");

        String theFileName = "SAI_Report_gen_" + simpleDateFormat.format(calendar.getTime()) + ".pdf";

        String pathName = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/SAIChatbot";

        File file = new File(pathName);

        if (!file.exists())
            file.mkdir();

        pdfDocument.writeTo(new FileOutputStream(new File(pathName, theFileName)));

        SAIHelper.createAndShowToast(getActivity(), "PDF Generated");
    }
```

And for the layout xmls:

**table_layout.xml**

```
<TableLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:stretchColumns="*"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:id="@+id/tableLayoutMain">

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="10sp"
            android:fontFamily="@font/avenir_bold"
            android:text="PERCENTAGE"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="@color/darkGrey" />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="10sp"
            android:fontFamily="@font/avenir_bold"
            android:text="CATEGORY"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="@color/darkGrey" />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="10sp"
            android:fontFamily="@font/avenir_bold"
            android:text="AVG SCORE"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="@color/darkGrey" />
    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

**row_layout.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableRow
    android:id="@+id/tableRowMain"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
</TableRow>
```

The following is a screenshot of the generated PDF file:
[PDF](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iJh8E.png)

As you can see, only the inflated `TableLayout` prior to the addition of the child views is drawn to the PDF.

But when I experimented on displaying the `TableLayout` to verify if the structure is valid, it successfuly displayed.

I tried putting `TableLayout.LayoutParams()` for the `TableLayout` and `TableRow.LayoutParams()` for the `TableRow` and to no avail, it doesn't work.

I have also tried to experiment on `requestLayout()` and `invalidate()` methods to see if the issue revolves around refreshing the TableLayout after adding child TableRows dynamically, still, no luck.

I have spent days on how to implement this functionality of mine, and I would appreciate it if you could help me with my current predicament.